# Getting values from accelerometer class to main activity class

Tags: java, android, class, accelerometer

I'm trying to make an Android App that reads accelerometer values and sends them to the server.  I have two classes in two files - the Main class with httpget method and the accelerometer class.

I receive nothing from the onSensorChanged method (I send values through making new object from accellerometer class), or my accellerometer class doesn't work.

Questions:
1) Can you give me a small example, when I have an Accelerometer class and I read values in another class?

2) Should I start the accelerometer class from the main activity?

I would be very grateful if you can answer my question and give me a small example!

Answer (score 0):

Please check out the source code. Here is example source code about Accelerometer.

[Link](http://developer.android.com/resources/samples/AccelerometerPlay/src/com/example/android/accelerometerplay/AccelerometerPlayActivity.html)

I think it help you.

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit unclear, so from the following assumptions:

File 1: Server thread with httpget

File 2: Reads accelerometer data and sends it to the server thread

You are in a debug environment where you're running them together to test it.

There seems to be a bit of confusion on names here.  Just because you have an Accelerometer class, doesn't mean the code is active and running.  If you just start up one with its main method, and it makes no reference to the other object, then that code will never run.

```
public class Server
{
  public void onSensorChanged()
  {
    //do stuff to listen for accelerometer data
  }
  public static void main(String args[])
  {
    onSensorChanged();
  }
}
```

If just this runs, there is nobody reading the accelerometer data.

```
public class Accelerometer implements Runnable
{
  public void run()
  {
    while (!dead)
    {
      //read data
      //send to server
      //wait for a bit?
    } 
  }
}
```

So we add a line to the Server main method

```
new Thread(new Accelerometer()).start();
```

1) I'm not sure what you're asking.  Class 1 gets data from sensors and class 2 reads it from class 1 to send it to the server?
2) Yes, if you need more than one thread running, your entry point will need to start both.  Or they need to be started seperatly